Discrepancies between GA4 UI and GA4 bigquery
I'm trying to replicate some number in bigquery. However, when I compare the numbers with GA the differences are remarkable and Bigquery results shows higher number. Any tip would be highly appreciated. In this example, I've tried to get the number of sessions by source and medium from the website:
SELECT
Distinct
CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST((SELECT value.int_value FROM tbl.event_params WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS STRING)) AS sessions,
       FIRST_VALUE(traffic_source.source) OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST((SELECT value.int_value FROM tbl.event_params WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS STRING)) ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC) AS source,
       FIRST_VALUE(traffic_source.medium) OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, CAST((SELECT value.int_value FROM tbl.event_params WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS STRING)) ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC) AS medium
       
        FROM tbl 
where 

             device.web_info.hostname is not null 


Something you may want to check on is whether any sampling or thresholding is taking place in the UI; it's quite common to see differences vs the raw data due to these effects.
